# ASP.NET MVC URL Routing with Multiple Route Values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am having trouble with Html.ActionLink when I have a route that takes more than one parameter. For example, given the following routes defined in my Global.asax file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Tagging",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{tags}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", tags = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SlugsAfterId",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Browse", id = "", slug = "" }
);
```

The first two routes work without a problem, but when I try to create an action link to the third route using:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(product.Name), "Details", new { id = product.ProductId, slug = Html.Encode(product.Name) }) %>
```

I end up with a URL like **[site-root]/Details/1?slug=url-slug** whereas I would like the URL to be more like **[site-root]/Details/1/url-slug**

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: I've always had this kind of issue and never found an acceptable solution other than hard-coding the controller and action names.  Leads to LOTS of routes.

Comment: you could look at the restful routing for ASP.NET MVC project http://stevehodgkiss.com/2009/10/11/restful-routes-for-asp-net-mvc.html 
I use this and can achieve urls such as /blogs/1/posts/2/comments/3

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is using the first route that is fully satisfied. Try putting your `SlugsAfterId` route above the `Default` one.

It's basically going: "Check Default. Got an action? Yes. Got an id? Yes. Use this one and chuck any other parameters in the querystring."

As a side note, doing that will make your `Default` route redundant as you provide a default value for the `slug` parameter.

Answer (score 32):

Garry (above) is correct. You can use Mr. Haack's route debugger for MVC.  It can help resolve routing issues by showing you which routes are hit and when.

Here is the [Blog Post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).
And here is the [Zip File](http://haacked.com/code/RouteDebug-Binary.zip).

Answer (score 8):

You could add a Constraint to your Routes that contain "id" since it's presumably only to accept a number. This way the first route will only match when the "id" is numeric, then it would make the second route for all other values. Then place the one that includes the {slug} at the top and everything should work correctly.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SlugsAfterId",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Browse", id = "", slug = "" },
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },  // Parameter defaults
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Tagging",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{tags}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", tags = "" }
);
```