# MVC 3 url parameters rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've this routing map:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ViewNews",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "NewsDetail", id = "", title = "" }
        );
```

and this ActionLink in my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "NewsDetail", new { id = Model.Id, title = Url.ToFriendlyUrl(Model.Title) })
```

I expect it renders something like this:

```
http://localhost:49327/Home/NewsDetail/1/news-title
```

instead it renders:

```
http://localhost:49327/Home/NewsDetail/1?title=news-title
```

what I miss?

**Update**

I've moved MapRoute before default in this way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ViewNews",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "NewsDetail", id = "", title = "" }
        );


routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults

        );
```

but now when I request the initial URL:

```
http://localhost:49327/Home
```

I get instantly redirected to:

```
http://localhost:49327/Home/NewsDetail/1/news-title
```

"NewsDetail" has become the default action!

[image]

Comment: This answer will probably help you, along with @Darin's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734249/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-with-multiple-route-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `Model.Id` parameter is not null or empty and that the Default route is not before the one you have shown in your Global.asax. You need to remove it or place it after this custom route.

Comment: That's normal. The 2 routes are mutually exclusive. You will need to define some constraints. For example if your ids are always numeric you could define a numeric regex constraint on the first route.